# Php static child classes inheritance

Tags: php, oop

I recently began to develop in php5 in an object oriented way and I'm stuck at something. I would really appreciate your help/recommendations.

Bear with me in this since it ended up in a mess :-(

This is my scenario (hope I can elaborate on this clearly): I have two dynamic classes, Client and Supplier which use methods of a static class called Vocabulary. Vocabulary is a class that pulls vocabulary terms from a source which can be: plain text file, mongodb database or mysql database. An entry in a configuration file determines which of the
aforementioned three types of sources the application will use.

```
class Client {
    public function foo() {
        ...
        Vocabulary::getTerm();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class Supplier {
    public function bar() {
        ...
        Vocabulary::getTerm();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class Vocabulary {
    public static function useVocab($vocab) {
        $_SESSION['vocab'] = $vocab;
    }
    public static function getTerm($termKey) {...}
    ...
}
```

I planned to create Vocabulary child classes for each of the types I want to support, for example: Vocabulary_file, Vocabulary_mongodb and Vocabulary_mysql.
Vocabulary_file will override its parent useVocab() because it needs to perform additional operations appart from setting the $_SESSION variable, but
Vocabulary_mongodb and Vocabulary_mysql don't need to override their useVocab() parent method (they just need the $_SESSION variable set).
All three Vocabulary "child" classes will override getTerm() method.

The following is what I tried and this is the mess I ended up with :-(

- For Vocabulary_mongodb and Vocabulary_mysql, since useVocab() doesn't exist but is inherited from Vocabulary, "method_exists()" returns true and that call
  causes an infinite loop.
- I looks weird both calling the child explicitly in Vocabulary and calling the parent:: in the child class.

After lots of cups of coffee I have exhausted all my wits and my brain is damaged.

```
// Class Vocabulary modified to make it call the desired "child" class too
class Vocabulary {
    // This would execute "child" class method
    private static function _callChild($method, $args) {
        $child_class = 'Vocabulary_' . Config::$vocab['type']; // Config::$vocab['type']     can be: file, mongodb or mysql
        if (method_exists($child_class, $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array($child_class . '::' . $method, $args);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function useVocab($vocab) {
        $_SESSION['vocab'] = $vocab;
        self::_callChild(__FUNCTION__, compact('vocab'));
    }
    public static function getTerm($termKey) {
        $termKey = strtolower($termKey);
        self::_callChild(__FUNCTION__, compact('termKey'));
    }
    ...
}

class Vocabulary_file extends Vocabulary {
    public static function useVocab($vocab) {
        parent::useVocab($vocab);
        // some specific stuff here
    }
    public static function getTerm($termKey) {
        parent::getTerm($termKey);
        // some specific stuff here
    }
}

class Vocabulary_mongodb extends Vocabulary {
    public static function getTerm($termKey) {
        parent::getTerm($termKey);
        // some specific stuff here
    }
}

class Vocabulary_mysql extends Vocabulary {
    public static function getTerm($termKey) {
            parent::getTerm($termKey);
        // some specific stuff here
    }
}
```

I would like to know how can I design the Vocabulary classes in order to keep the Vocabulary::... like calls in Client and Supplier and let Vocabulary know which child class use for the type configured in "Config" class.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: `I recently began to develop in php5 in an object oriented way`?? making classes with statics is a fancy way to write procedural code

Comment: @JvdBerg I'd like to see how you'd implement a singleton in php without having static properties and methods.  Statics != procedural

Comment: @JvdBerg Well it's a step in the right direction. At least the methods are reusable.

Comment: @Ray: I use a IoC container, that can hold one instance of a class. No need to program a singleton. A Registry also could do that job.

Comment: @webnoob: a single function is also reusable

Comment: Thanks for your input JvdBerg. I thought it was a good idea to make static classes for all the stuff that is helper-like functions. When should I use static classes? I'm still learning :)

Comment: @RolandPish: There is virtually no need to use statics. If you start using OOP then you would not need them. When writing classes, keep testability in mind.

Comment: I'll disagree with @JvdBerg to the extend that statics are useful as *alternative constructors*. Anywhere you write a class name anyway, you may also call a static function of that class. E.g. instead of `$obj = new Foo;`, `$obj = Foo::instantiate();` is also acceptable. This is pretty much the only time you want to use `static` methods. Otherwise you're not doing OOP, you're doing *Class* oriented programming, which doesn't really differ from regular function calls.

Comment: @deceze: I agree with you, my comment was geared to someone who has thought he had been started with OOP

Comment: Aren't static classes in PHP kept in memory with Global scope until the process is terminated? If that is the case then they would be better off for helper functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using all `static` methods, you may as well not use OOP at all, it's basically all just global function calls. If you want inheritance with polymorphism to work, you pretty much need to instantiate your classes. The polymorphism then comes from the fact that the instantiated objects can be anything, but you're calling the same methods on them. E.g.:

```
abstract class Vocabulary {

    abstract public function getTerm($termKey);

}

class Vocabulary_File extends Vocabulary {

    public function getTerm($termKey) {
        // get from file
    }

}

class Vocabulary_MySQL extends Vocabulary {

    public function getTerm($termKey) {
        // get from database
    }

}
```

You can use this polymorphic like this:

```
if (mt_rand(0, 1)) {
    $vocab = new Vocabulary_File;
} else {
    $vocab = new Vocabulary_MySQL;
}

// This call is polymorphic.
//  What exactly it does depends on which class was instantiated.
$vocab->getTerm('foo');
```

This is how polymorphism is really useful. The interface (`getTerm($termKey)`) is defined and unchanging between classes, but the specific implementation changes. If your code is hardcoding calls to `Vocabulary::getTerm()`, that's not polymorphism. With your structure you're also violating an important OO design rule: The parent does not know about its children, and it does not interact with its children. The children override functionality of the parent, not the other way around.

You also shouldn't use the `$_SESSION` as a form of global storage. Keep objects self contained.

Comment: How do you implement a singleton  pattern without static variables and methods?  static != global.

Comment: @Ray Nope, `static` === namespaced global. Tell me, what's the difference between `bar()` and `Foo::bar()`? I did not say you need  to avoid all `static`, I'm saying it's wrongheaded for *polymorphism*, which is what the OP is interested in. Static methods are just function calls. Try implementing polymorphism with function calls.

Comment: you can add public, private, protected scoping to Foo::bar(). Second it's namespaced to the class's namespace http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php not the global namespace

Comment: @Ray Exactly, as I'm saying, `static` === namespaced global. So the only advantage is visibility modifiers. Cool, but not something fundamentally different from function calls. I'll voluntarily add that you can share namespaced, visibility modified data between function. You can do the exact same things using functions though, minus the visibility modifiers. Now, are visibility modifiers something so extraordinary that you need to use OOP for it? Not really. You need to start instantiating objects to get the real benefit. Benefits like polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `self` suffers from inability to handle 'late-static-binding'.  Basically, in the parent class, `self` thinks it's the parent class when it's inside it's own static functions (since `self` is still evaluated at compile time for legacy reasons).

You need to use `static` instead of `self` in the parent class (assuming you have php 5.3 or higher).

BTW: the `parent` keyword functions as you'd expect as the `parent` has to be known at compile time anyhow.

Here's an example:

```
public static function getTerm($termKey) {
    $termKey = strtolower($termKey);
    static::_callChild(__FUNCTION__, compact('termKey'));
}
```

If you're using php 5.2 and earlier, you have to try a hack around, like require all child classes to have static functions that return their class name.  I hope you're on php 5.3 or higher...